# idiomatic iteration over range and set in maxima

Tags: maxima

beginner's question.  what is the idiomatic expression in maxima to accomplish the equivalent R expression

```
for (i in c(1:5,29,155)) message(i)
1,2,3,4,5,29,155
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a function for each value in a list and you don't care about the return value (i.e., you're interested a side effect such as printing), you can say:

```
for x in mylist do print(x);
```

If you want the return value of, say, `f`, for each element,

```
makelist (f(x), x, mylist);
```

Maxima doesn't have a built-in range operator, so something like `1:5` is the slightly more verbose `makelist(i, i, 1, 5)`.

Also, while in R `c(c(c(...), ...), ...)` effectively collapses any nested vectors, Maxima lets nested lists stand (`flatten` flattens nested lists). In the example given, try `append(mypartiallist, [29, 155])` where `mypartiallist` is the stuff from the previous `makelist`.

Comment: add definition itself: `mylist: append( makelist( i, i, 1, 5 ), [29, 255]);`